# Dynamic graph generation from .csv file using JFreeChart

Tags: swing, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to generate line graphs from a simple array of integers.
However, I'd like to use a csv file for the input of the graph. Are there any applications which do it automatically? Also, my csv file will new entries appended every 3 seconds. How can I generate dynamic graphs? I will have to use these graphs in a swing application. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with [`org.h2.tools.Csv`](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Csv.html), part of [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com). You might also look at [`org.jfree.data.io.CSV`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/io/CSV.html), "A utility class for reading `CategoryDataset` data from a CSV file."